# Is there a way to update top level relationship in Django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have below models and form.

Brand > Section > Category > Article.

I can pull the existing data out of the database however I have hit a wall. I am trying to create a new article or update an existing article but I'm not sure how I can update the brand, then the Section. The Category I can update and it is connected directly to the Article model. I have been thinking about this for a few days now and tried different models but ultimately i can't think of the best way to connect the models and have them update in the model.

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    
    def brand_image(instance, filename):
        return 'uploads/brand/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.title, filename)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=brand_image, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with='title', blank=True, null=True)
    my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['my_order']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title or ''

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('brand-list', kwargs={'brand_slug': self.slug})
    

class Section(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True, blank=True,null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with='title',blank=True,null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='section', blank=False, null=False)
    my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['my_order']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title or ''
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('section-list', kwargs={'section_slug': self.slug})

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with='title',blank=True,null=True)
    my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='category', blank=False ,null=False)    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['my_order']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title or ''
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category-list', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=PROTECT, related_name='article', null=False, default=1)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with='created__month')
    content = HTMLField(null=True,blank=True)
    internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Draft')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author' ,on_delete=PROTECT,null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='updated_by',on_delete=PROTECT,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    video = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='articles/videos')
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='art_favourite', default=None, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(related_name='tags', help_text='Comma or space separated list', blank=True)
    pinned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles-detail', kwargs={'article_slug': self.slug})

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
        
    title = forms.CharField(label='Article Title', max_length=100,)
    description = forms.CharField(label='Description', max_length=100,required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(label='Article Content',widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
    video = forms.FileField(help_text="Valid file Extension - .mp4", required=False, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    category = GroupedModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.exclude(section=None).order_by('section'),choices_groupby='section')
    internal = forms.BooleanField(required=False, help_text='Is this for internal use only?', label='Internal Article')
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ['slug','author','created','updated','updated_by','favourites','votes','views','section']
        widgets = {"tags": TagWidget(attrs={"data-role": "tagsinput"})}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you have already tried this or if it may works. I would probably go with a form showing the article, its foreignkey to category, category foreign key to section, and section foreign key to brand. And for each of them a dropdown menu showing the other available options. When selecting a new value for any Model, get the Object, and alter its foreign key. It should not modify the objects depending on it. If it's not possible to modify the foreign keys, I would probably go with ManyToManyField, however you will need to do some other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Article model has a foreign key link to Section for some reason.  However your stated heirarchy and models use the following one-to-many relations, which creates a direct link up the chain.

Brand < Section < Category < Article.

This means that by choosing the Category you could also choose Brand and Section. If your Article had a foreign key link to Category instead, then all the information above about groups above Article could be obtained via the article, eg, `article.category__section__brand`. Changing the category would, by default, update section and brand. You could do this in a single dropdown that contained Category.objects.all - perhaps with the dropdown option text also containing brand and section info for clarity and sorting purposes.

Comment: Ahh sorry about that. I was playing with the models and trying to link the Article directly to each other model.

My problem is, I'm not sure how to reflect this on the form. In the html page I know how to pull the relationship data but in the form, it's not so dynamic as the page is built on the server.

Comment: You'll need some element of javscript to create dynamic, conditional forms like that as django doesn't handle it natively without pageload. In this case, because you're generating HTML, you might want to look at the HTMX library to generate three dropdowns in sequence, eg, selecting from the brand dropdown then shows a dropdown with appropriate sections etc. HTMX lets you use django templates to generate the partial HTML without worrying about serialisers etc.

Comment: Thank you @SamSparx. Looking into htmx now. It looks really powerful and will give me a tone of other features as well.